# Reading SQL Tables from MS SQL Server with connectorx in Python

Tags: python, sql-server, pyarrow, python-polars

I am trying to read sql tables from MS SQL Server 2014 with connectorx in Python Polars in Jupyter Notebook.

My code:

```
#importing libraries

import pyarrow
from connectorx import read_sql
import polars as pl
import os
import gensim
import spacy
import csv
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#loading spacy language model

nlp = spacy.load("de_core_news_lg")

#reading sql tables and creating connection

connection = "mssql://username:password@PAMUK5AM100:1433/db"
user = "SELECT * FROM v_Text"
questions = "SELECT * FROM v_Questions"

#reading sql tables and creating dataframes

user_df = pl.read_sql(user, connection)

questions_df = pl.read_sql(questions, connection)
```

After running this I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [24], in <cell line: 3>()
      1 #reading sql tables and creating dataframes
----> 3 user_df = pl.read_sql(user, connection)
      5 questions_df = pl.read_sql(questions, connection)

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\polars\io.py:1105, in read_sql(sql, connection_uri, partition_on, partition_range, partition_num, protocol)
   1100 except ImportError:
   1101     raise ImportError(
   1102         "connectorx is not installed. Please run `pip install connectorx>=0.3.1`."
   1103     ) from None
-> 1105 tbl = cx.read_sql(
   1106     conn=connection_uri,
   1107     query=sql,
   1108     return_type="arrow2",
   1109     partition_on=partition_on,
   1110     partition_range=partition_range,
   1111     partition_num=partition_num,
   1112     protocol=protocol,
   1113 )
   1115 return cast(DataFrame, from_arrow(tbl))

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\connectorx\__init__.py:257, in read_sql(conn, query, return_type, protocol, partition_on, partition_range, partition_num, index_col)
    254 except ModuleNotFoundError:
    255     raise ValueError("You need to install pyarrow first")
--> 257 result = _read_sql(
    258     conn,
    259     "arrow" if return_type in {"arrow", "polars"} else "arrow2",
    260     queries=queries,
    261     protocol=protocol,
    262     partition_query=partition_query,
    263 )
    264 df = reconstruct_arrow(result)
    265 if return_type in {"polars", "polars2"}:

RuntimeError: Timed out in bb8
```

What am I doing wrong? I have already installed pyarrow and connectorx, but still keep getting this error. Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: what do you get if you do pl.show_versions()  Also, maybe try to not import connectorx or pyarrow.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor 
Hi, I ran pl.show_versions() and this is what I get -

---Version info---
Polars: 0.15.15
Index type: UInt32
Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19044-SP0
Python: 3.9.12 (main, Apr  4 2022, 05:22:27) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
---Optional dependencies---
pyarrow: 11.0.0
pandas: 1.4.2
numpy: 1.21.5
fsspec: 2022.02.0
connectorx: 0.3.1
xlsx2csv: <not installed>
matplotlib: 3.5.1

How can I read sql files without connectorx or pyarrow for Polars? The Polars documentation recommends that I use connectorx for this.
Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to have them imported in your script for polars (or whichever library) to use them.  To be honest, it's unlikely that removing the import lines will be the fix.  The likely fix is uninstalling and reinstalling because it seems you've got a environment/install issue.  It's just that removing (or commenting out) the import lines is super low effort so it's worth a shot incase it's getting "confused" with the imported `get_sql` imported from connectorx while you're using `pl.read_sql`